# generic check for null, not for default (T)

Tags: c#, .net, json, generics

How can i determine if value of generic method is null? So only way i found is check that it's a class and it has default value. So my code:

```
    public static string AsJsonArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
        bool isClass = typeof (T).IsClass;
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (isClass && enumerator.Current == default(T))
                sb.Append("null");
            else 
                sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
                if (isClass && enumerator.Current == default(T))
                    sb.Append("null");
                else
                    sb.Append(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }

        var asJsonArray = sb.Append("]").ToString();
        return asJsonArray;
    }
```

but i'm really annoyed by this ugly reflection check `isClass && enumerator.Current == default(T)`

Do any alternative exist?

Comment: You can use `ReferenceEquals()`.

Comment: How do you want it to handle the case where `T` is a `Nullable<Foo>` and the value is a null value for that nullable type?

Comment: @JonSkeet what return `default(Nullable<Foo>)`? struct with `HasValue==false`?

Comment: Note than `IsClass` is not an enough indicator of whether `T` is a reference type (since it may also be an interface). `if( ! typeof(T).IsValueType)` is more robust.

Comment: @Grundy: Well I'm asking the question - I don't know what the OP wants to do in that case.

Comment: @JonSkeet i simply want clarify this for yourself :-)

Comment: @JonSkeet I expect null-behaviour in this case. Well, ReferenceEquals should help me here.

Comment: @Grundy ReferenceEquals for `new int?()` returns `true`.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: That's because `new int?()` is a null value, basically. It will box to a null reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need `== null`:

```
var current = enumerator.Current;
if (current == null)
{
    sb.Append("null");
}
else
{
    sb.Append(current);
}
```

Or more compactly:

```
var current = enumerator.Current;
sb.Append(current == null ? (object) "null" : current);
```

Or even by boxing *before* the call, and using the null-coalescing operator:

```
object current = enumerator.Current; // Boxes where necessary
sb.Append(current ?? "null");
```

Comment: Thanks, i just was thinking that I'm not able to use `==` operator with unknown `T` type.

Comment: @AlexJoukovsky: You can *only* use it with `null`.

Answer (score 4):

As comments suggest, use the `==` operator or a `ReferenceEquals` check.

```
private static bool IsNull<T>(T item)
{
   return object.ReferenceEquals(null, item);
}
```

This yields:

```
int? nullableInt = null;
Console.WriteLine(IsNull(nullableInt)); //true
object refType = null;
Console.WriteLine(IsNull(refType)); //true
int valueType = 0;
Console.WriteLine(IsNull(valueType)); //false
```

The `IsClass` check you do would fail for the `Nullable<T>` because `Nullable` is actually a `struct`.

To remove duplicate code you could even create a method to check for null and replace with text:

```
private static string ToStringOrDefault<T>(T item, string replacement = "null")
{
    return IsNull(item) ? replacement : item.ToString();
}

sb.Append(ToStringOrDefault(nullableInt));
```

Comment: @Servy it is when you box it to an `object` by calling `object.ReferenceEquals`.